# which live/rescue disk it is which gives you an option to boot into your GNU/Linux OS without grub?

Tags: debian, grub, rescue

I remember a live CD/DVD where I could just boot into my GNU/Linux partition in case your grub was shot. The simplest thing was once in your GNU/Linux partition, install grub-pc and its brethen and simply do update-grub and all would be well. I tried grml and know it's not grml, maybe knoppix or some other live-rescue distro ?

Comment: When you have a UEFI system you don't need grub when the kernel is built with EFISTUB (which current Debian kernels are). So in case your grub installation is broken you can directly boot the kernel from the UEFI and fix your grub afterwards.

Comment: what if it's NOT an EUFI system, such old systems still are there you know :)

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is to use isohybrid_bios_efi_grubrescue image meaning you can boot either as cd or usb on either oldPal_biosPC or on newer uefiPC
and 
           you are in grub commands in any of these cases
see demo and explanation here

https://sourceforge.net/projects/toysbox/files/bios-efi_GrubRescue/

tested on "old i686 2GB" and on "Acer Nitro efi 4Gb"

enjoy